# Type of skin retouching and Dramatic effects added?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

Im a graphic designer and youtuber who wants to improve the overall quality of my thumbnails. What skin retouching/effects could i learn to achieve this effect on the subject. Any learning resources or tutorials?

[image]

Comment: Hi. I don't think there is any significant skin retouching in that image to be honest. Maybe a little extra contrast/levels/curves tweaks to make it pop.  As for the rest it's a photomanipulation. There are many techniques, using images from elsewhere, layer masking, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Im familiar with some of them. But for the most part. I thought maybe someone knew of a technique or tutorial to make those tweaks that make it "pop".

Comment: There's a useful tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33-Ai-50Nes

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you look for an easy solution you may be happy with the **[G'Mic](https://gmic.eu/) Mighty Details** filter:

[image: Original] [image: Mighty Details]
<sup>Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Marilyn_Monroe,_Photoplay_1953.jpg)</sup>

Above is *Mighty Details* filter set to Amplitude 100 and defaults in the additional settings.

These filters are available as a plugin for GIMP, Krita, Photoshop, Affinity Photo, PaintShop Pro, PhotoLine and Paint.NET, or as an [online version](https://gmicol.greyc.fr/) to try them out.